# Multiprocessing spawns idle processes and doesn't compute anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

There seems to be a litany of questions and answers on overflow about the multiprocessing library. I have looked through all the relevant ones I can find all and have not found one that directly speaks to my problem.

I am trying to apply the same function to multiple files in parallel. Whenever I start the processing though, the computer just spins up several instances of python and then does nothing. No computations happen at all and the processes just sit idle

I have looked at all of the similar questions on overflow, and none seem to have my problem of idle processes.

what am i doing wrong?

define the function (abbreviated for example. checked to make sure it works)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
#from timeit import default_timer as timer
import talib
from multiprocessing import Process


def example_function(file):

    df=pd.read_csv(file, header = 1)
    stock_name = os.path.basename(file)[:-4]
    macd, macdsignal, macdhist = talib.MACD(df.Close, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)

    df['macd'] = macdhist*1000
    print(f'stock{stock_name} processed')
    final_macd_report.append(df)
```

getting a list of all the files in the directory i want to run the function on

```
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\josiahh\Desktop\big_test3/*'

files = [f for f in glob.glob(path, recursive=True)]
```

attempting multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp
if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = mp.Pool(processes = 5)
    async_result = p.map_async(example_function, files)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Complete")
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Except from `filepath` not being defined in `exemple_function` it looks basically OK. In the first code block you're importing `Process`. And from the glob path you seem to be running ms-windows. Make sure you're starting processes outside of `__main__`.

Comment: @RolandSmith, thanks for the catch on the function. That was an artifact of me shrinking the code down for the example. I moved the start of the process outsiede of the __main__ part of the code, but the processes still just start up as idle processes and dont do anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, excuse my ignorance, but I think I am using the map functionality instead of the application functionality in my code? I dont think i use apply anywhere in it. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. ``map_async`` is fine.

Comment: I made a typo, on ms-windows processes should *only* be started *inside* `__main__`. This has to do with the way multiprocessing is implemented on ms-windows.

Comment: I added the `jupyter-notebook` and `windows` tags, since they seem to be crucial for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the structure of the code, so something is going wrong that can't be guessed from what you posted.  Start with something very much simpler, then move it in stages to what you're actually trying to do.  You're importing mountains of extension (3rd party) code, and the problem could be anywhere.  Here's a start:

```
def example_function(arg):
    from time import sleep
    msg = "crunching " + str(arg)
    print(msg)
    sleep(arg)
    print("done " + msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing as mp
    p = mp.Pool(processes = 5)
    async_result = p.map_async(example_function, reversed(range(15)))
    print("result", async_result.get())
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Complete")
```

That works fine on Win10 under 64-bit Python 3.7.4 for me.  Does it for you?

Note especially the `async_result.get()` at the end.  That displays a list with 15 `None` values.  You never do anything with your `async_result`.  Because of that, if any exception was raised in a worker process, it will most likely silently vanish.  In such cases `.get()`'ing the result will (re)raise the exception in your main program.

Also please verify that your `files` list isn't in fact empty.  We can't guess at that from here either ;-)

### EDIT

I moved the `async_result.get()` into its own line, right after the `map_async()`, to maximize the chance of revealing otherwise silent exception in the worker processes.  At least add that much to your code too.

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer. I copy and pasted your code and it does not work on my system. It spawns idle processes and nothing happens. I guess that means something is wrong with my installation of the library?

Comment: What library?  The code I showed uses nothing outside the core Python distribution.  Exactly which version of Python are you using, where did you get it from, and exactly how are you running it?  For example, if you're running under some fancy IDE, _that_ can cause problems too.  Try running it from a "DOS box" (`cmd.exe` terminal window). `path_to_python.exe name_of_file.py`

Comment: I'm using the basic anaconda installation of python on a windows 7 64 bit machine. Python version 3.6.8 I assumed maybe the multiprocessing library was somehow improperly installed or something like that?

Comment: everything is run in a Jupiter notebook. Does multiprocessing not work in jupiter?

Comment: Please try it in a "DOS box".  There's no point speculating until we find a scenario under which the very simple sample code _does_ work.  It should work just fine under every version of Python ever since the `multiprocessing` module was created.  I can't _guess_ from here, so please just try the things that are suggested.  BTW, I haven't used Jupyter.

Comment: tried it in a DOS box and it worked fine. Thats the first time i have ever gotten the multiprocessing library to work on my machine

Comment: OK!  So it's not a problem with your Python installation.  My _guess_ is that it's Jupyter that doesn't play with `multiprocessing` on Windows.  Use the StackOverflow search box and look for "python multiprocessing jupyter". You'll find more than one possibly relevant hit.  But since I haven't used Jupyter, I can't help you guess which will get you unstuck.  In the meantime, use a DOS box ;-)

Comment: You're welcome - but at least give my answer a single upvote on the way out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't see anything *wrong* per se, I would like to suggest some changes.

In general, worker functions in a `Pool` are expected to return something. This return value is transferred back to the parent process. I like to use that as a status report. It is also a good idea to catch exceptions in the worker process, just in case.
For example:

```
def example_function(file):
    status = 'OK'
    try:
        df=pd.read_csv(file, header = 1)
        stock_name = os.path.basename(file)[:-4]
        macd, macdsignal, macdhist = talib.MACD(df.Close, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
        df['macd'] = macdhist*1000
        final_macd_report.append(df)
   except:
       status = 'exception caught!'
   return {'filename': file, 'result': status}
```

(This is just a quick example. You might want to e.g. report the full exception traceback to help with debugging.)

If workers run for a long time, I like to get feedback ASAP.
So I prefer to use `imap_unordered`, especially if some tasks can take much longer than others. This returns an iterator that yields results *in the order that jobs finish*.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    with mp.Pool() as p:
        for res in p.imap_unordered(example_function, files):
            print(res)
```

This way you get *unambiguous proof* that a worker finished, and what the result was and if any problems occurred.

This is preferable over just calling `print` from the workers. With stdout buffering and multiple workers inheriting the same output stream there is no saying when you actually see something.

**Edit**: As you can see [here](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac), `multiprocessing.Pool` does not work well with interactive interpreters, especially on ms-windows. Basically, ms-windows lacks the `fork` system call that lets UNIX-like systems duplicate a process. So on ms-windows, `multiprocessing` has to do a try and mimic `fork` which means importing the original program file in the child processes. That  doesn't work well with interactive interpreters like IPython. One would probably have to dig deep into the internals of Jupyter and `multiprocessing` to find out the exact cause of the problem.

It seems that a *workaround* for this problem is to define the worker function in a separate module and import that in your code in IPython.

It *is* actually mentioned in the documentation that `multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't work well with interactive interpreters. See the note at the end of [this section](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

Comment: thank you as well for the very thorough answer! This also did not work for me and led to the spawning of idle processes and nothing else.

Comment: @JosiahHulsey See the **Edit** section. I cannot test this myself since I'm not running ms-windows.